# When you sweep a private key at Blockchain can you sweep the key in HEX format?

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key

It would be useful to know this because I have made a 64 character hex private key by hand and generated the address without storing the key in WIF format. I don’t want to go online, input the hex key and have it rejected.

Of course I could try it out with a small amount in a sloppy wallet, but it would be easier for someone to tell me.

Comment: WIF stands for "Wallet Interchange Format" - the standard way for importing/exporting bitcoin private keys. Yes, it is possible to keep private keys in HEX, BASE64 and 100500 other formats. But why should anyone implement them?

Comment: Why? Because I made a random 64 character hex key not using a computer. And offline, I found the B58Check address which that key makes and then paid some Bitcoin into it.  I now want to redeem the money.

Comment: You can use https://brainwallet.github.io/ (1) set "Get Address From" to "Secret Exponent" (2) type your hex key into the field "Secret Exponent" (3) get your private key in WIF format in the field "Private Key"

Comment: @amaclin: That is precisely what he says, in his second sentence, that he *doesn't* want to do.